# Efficient LINQ to select positional index of object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have Entity Framework models with int properties that look like these:

```
Orb
-OrbID
-GlobeID
-(Non int property)
-(Non int property)

Globe
-GlobeID
-SystemID
-(Non int property)
-(Non int property)

System
-SystemID
-(Non int property)
-(Non int property)
```

Visually a sample layout looks like this:

```
System 1           System 2
-Globe 1 (Empty)      -Globe 4 
-Globe 3               -Orb 4
 -Orb 1              -Globe 5 
 -Orb 2                -Orb 6
                       -Orb 8
```

The IDs (placed on the right in the visual) are incremented based on creation of each object, so a leading Orb that is deleted with index 3 will cause next created Orb to have an index of 4. Indices are not relative to the parent.

Since I have the IDs, I want to get the position of Orbs. So for Orb 6, which is System 2, Globe 5, Orb 6, I want to get 2,2,1 (2nd System, 2nd Globe, 1st Orb).  The database will probably not get so big (Maybe around 20 Globes with 5 Orbs each). The first ID I will get is an external ID that I can query to get the Orb ID from, so OrbID is the only immediately available one.

This is a code that would work

```
var systems = db.Systems.Select((x, sindex) => new { x.Id, sindex });
var globes = db.Globes.Select((x, gindex) => new { x.Id, gindex, x.SystemID});
int orbID = db.SomeOtherTable.Where(s => s.someOtherID == someOtherID ).Select(x => x.OrbID).FirstOrDefault(); // to get OrbID
int globeID = db.Orbs.Where(s => s.OrbID == orbID).FirstOrDefault().GlobeID;
int orbIndex = db.Orbs.Where(x => x.GlobeID== globeID ).Select(x => x.OrbID).OrderBy(x => x).Select((x, index) => new { x, index }).Where(x => x.x == orbID).Select(x => x.index).FirstOrDefault();
//1 line to search for globeID on globes, get systemID
//1 line to match systemID from systems to get index to get systemIndex
//1 line to group globes by systemID, and get gindex of globe by matching through globeID (x.ID)
```

But I'm sure there's a much simpler and more efficient way to do this!

Comment: that seems like it is making 3 separate calls to the database. Try combining the `orbID` and `globeID` into one query. Also, the convenience of EF and LINQ comes at a price, so stored procedure or hardcoded SQL statement should be much faster.

Comment: Boo to Slai, EF and LINQ performs very adequately with SQL and it highly optimized.  Of course a stored procedure is faster but there's a reason we're not out writing hundreds of those anymore.

Comment: You just need to write this as a join and grouping.  The SQL will be optimized for a single query to the database then giving you the compared results you're looking for.